# Jasper Reports Change absolute path to relative path?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, relative-path

I am new to jasper, I want to compile the report in jrxml and export to pdf in from absolute path to relative path. Currently the codes work only in absolute path.

export to pdf = download folders of web browser
jrxml inside the /Reports/ConsumptionReport.jrxml (inside the web pages)
thank you :D

```
public void showReport(int productionNumber) throws JRException {

        try {




            DBConnectionFactory myFactory = DBConnectionFactory.getInstance();
            Connection conn = myFactory.getConnection();

            Map map = new HashMap();
            map.put("prodNum", productionNumber);

            JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("/Users/user/NetBeansProjects/EGMI/web/Reports/ConsumptionReport.jrxml");
            //Fill the report with parameter, connection and the stream reader     
            JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, map, conn);

            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp, "/Users/user/NetBeansProjects/EGMI/web/Reports/ConsumptionReport.pdf");
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

folder hierarchy

```
EGMI
   ---Web Pages
        ----Reports
               -----ConsumptionReport.jrxml
```

**SOLUTION- servlet**

```
String relativeWebPath = "/Reports";
           String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
           File f = new File(absoluteDiskPath, "ConsumptionReport.jrxml");
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5520421/59087

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use java.io.File to get the absolute path from a relative path. es.

```
File f = new File("yourRelativePath/ConsumptionReport.jrxml");
JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Seeing the problem to find the relative path of your deployed web application I suggest you check out these questions.

[Need to find the web application path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854554/need-to-find-the-web-application-path)

[What does servletcontext.getRealPath("/") mean and when should I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-servletcontext-getrealpath-mean-and-when-should-i-use-it/)

Comment: I changed it to   File f = new File("Reports/ConsumptionReport.jrxml");
            JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(f.getAbsolutePath()); but the problem now is it is getting the wrong path

Comment: You need to know from which relative path you start... try System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath()) to understand where you are...and what you are pointing to.

Comment: ava.io.FileNotFoundException: /Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/Reports/ConsumptionReport.jrxml  this is the error, is there a way to locate the relative path first?

Comment: the start of your relative path is: /Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/ it is set when applications start...

Comment: `File f = new File("/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/EGMI/web/Reports/ConsumptionReport.jrxml");` i tried this one but it is still not working, I will update my folder hierarchy in the question. thank you :))

Comment: Where are your reports?, in which folder??

Comment: i added the folders hierarchy above @petter

Comment: Add full path to reports...EGMI on your macchine in which folder is?, which is the correct absolute path?? /App.../domains/domani1/EGMI ?

Comment: Try this System.out.println(request.getContextPath()) and tell me what you got.. you need to try where you hve the request...

Comment: /Users/User/NetBeansProjects/EGMI this one? I dont know where does application/netbeans... is coming from

Comment: Its the path of the glass fish application that you run... To get the path of your deployed web application is different probably request.getContextPath() or similar can help you

Comment: I edit my post with some links on how to get the path to your deployed application, then just work your way to the report.